# Difference between MC1496 / LM1496 balanced modulator

Tags: modulation, balanced

I am working on a project that uses an [MC1496](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/mc1496-d.pdf), but unfortunately it’s not available here. Luckily I have found an [LM1496](http://www.mit.edu/%7E6.301/LM1496.pdf) which seems to be an alternative, but I have no clue how to bias it correctly for my application.
This is the schematic of the connection. I have tested it in simulation and it works.

[image]

As can be seen, the MC1496 is biased via single source, the BJT collector output is used to make the output at TTL levels.
However, in the datasheet of the LM1496 only dual bias is shown and there is no mention of single bias.
Also it says in the datasheet that it suppresses the carrier and that there is no need for an LPF filter, but that it has a 2nd-order passive connected to its output in the datasheet application example circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The LM1496 from National Semi (I think it was available at least by 1976, possibly earlier) was listed in the National databooks as a direct replacement for the MC1496 (which came out in 1972, I think.)

See [Bitsaver's copy of this 1989 databook from National](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/national/_dataBooks/1989_National_Data_Acquisition_Linear_Devices_Databook.pdf), for example:

[image]

If you check the [MC1496 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/mc1496-d.pdf) and the [LM1496 datasheet](https://www.mit.edu/%7E6.301/LM1496.pdf) then you will see the following:

[image]

The ***only*** apparent difference is that the MC1496 shows a diode (lower left corner) where the LM1496 more correctly shows a diode-connected BJT. But they are the same thing.

You can substitute one for the other.

The fact that you find the documentation of one of them to say some different things than the other is, I'm sure, more about the goals of marketing at the time. There is so much written on the MC1496 (including [AN531/D](https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.gatech.edu/dist/e/466/files/2015/01/mc1496apnote.pdf)) because, at the time circa 1972, they wanted to get out all the possible uses and provide both breadth and depth so that designers could use their imaginations more readily. I suspect that by the time National Semi got out their version (a little later) the marketing needs (for National anyway) had sharpened up a bit and so their datasheet likely reflects that. But this is just my guess.

Regardless, one can replace the other.

P.S.: *Just from my personal perspective, this is perhaps one of the finer contributions by [Barrie Gilbert](https://vintagetek.org/barrie-gilbert/).*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, yeah both have essentially the same schematic but I was afraid of the exact BJTs used in each one which might mean different bias conditions. As the data sheet input value limits differ,, I will definitely try to wire it up and test! Thanks again

Comment: @MohamedAbuain The one is intended to be a replacement for the other in all applications. I've used both and found no meaningful differences. You should be okay.